# Hibernate delete @OneToMany child directly form child object

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, jpa

I have a ReST API developed with Spring Boot that exposes resources. Using Spring Data JPA CrudRepository
One of this this resources contains a collection of another resource. I'd like to delete a child directly from its repository.

I have tried to use CascadeType = Remove but it still doesn't work.

Parent object :

```
@Entity
public class Subject{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String icon;

    private String image;

    @OneToMany( targetEntity=Ability.class, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Ability> abilities;
}
```

Child object :

```
@Entity
public class Ability {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String color;

    private String image;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Technology.class, orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private List<Technology> technologies;
```

But when I tried to delete an ability that is bound to a subject using :

```
abailityRepository.deleteById(id);
```

**I get following error message :**

> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.987258+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-08-04 13:34:27.986  WARN 4 --- [io-40382-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.987393+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-08-04 13:34:27.987 ERROR 4 --- [io-40382-exec-5] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: update or delete on table "ability" violates foreign key constraint "fkb019eiy6xjwsyxuukgmr9iid6" on table "subject_abilities"
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.987397+00:00 app[web.1]:   Detail: Key (id)=(100) is still referenced from table "subject_abilities".
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.987588+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-08-04 13:34:27.987  INFO 4 --- [io-40382-exec-5] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.987877+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-08-04 13:34:27.987 ERROR 4 --- [io-40382-exec-5] o.h.i.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl        : HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.993333+00:00 app[web.1]: 2019-08-04 13:34:27.992 ERROR 4 --- [io-40382-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkb019eiy6xjwsyxuukgmr9iid6]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.993338+00:00 app[web.1]: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "ability" violates foreign key constraint "fkb019eiy6xjwsyxuukgmr9iid6" on table "subject_abilities"
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.993340+00:00 app[web.1]:   Detail: Key (id)=(100) is still referenced from table "subject_abilities".
>
> 2019-08-04T13:34:27.993342+00:00 app[web.1]:   at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
> .......

Comment: You're missing the point of cascade. Cascade means: if you do X on subject, it will also do X on its abilities. So, in ths case, deleting a subject will also delete its abilities. That's not what you're doing in your code. You're trying to delete an ability, but it's still referenced by its subject, so it fails.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my point is to configure the @OnToMany without the ability deletion failing. 
I tried without and without Cascade but it still doesn't work. Which config should I use then ?

Comment: You shouldn't use "config". You should write the code that removes the ability from its subject before deleting the ability. Thans to the orphanRemoval, simply removing it from the list will be sufficient to also delete the ability.